# Looping values into a two-dimensional array with a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, console.readline

So I'm trying to loop values into a two-dimensional array using foreach. I know the code should look something like this.

```
        int calc = 0;
        int[,] userfields = new int[3,3];

        foreach (int userinput in userfields)
        {

            Console.Write("Number {0}: ", calc);
            calc++;
            userfields[] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

This is as far as I can get. I tried using

```
userfields[calc,0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

but apparently that doesn't work with two-dimensional arrays. I'm relatively new with C# and I'm trying to learn, so I appreciate all of the answers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What output do you want? A bit unclear from your question. Also, that code won't compile.

Comment: @shree.pat18 In the end I'm going to loop it out as a 3x3 table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a *two dimensional array* as the name suggests it has *two dimensions*. So you need to specify two index when you want to assign a value. Like:

```
// set second column of first row to value 2
userfield[0,1] = 2;
```

In this case probably you want a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userfield.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < userfield.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
       //TODO: validate the user input before parsing the integer
       userfields[i,j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

For more information have a look at:

- [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Comment: @Tatu If you found this answer helpful, consider upvoting and accepting. That is the customary way of saying thank you on Stack Exchange, and also informs the community that you feel your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am aware, I can't accept the answer just yet. I have to wait for a while before I can do that. I already upvoted though, and I will accept the answer I can do it! :)

Comment: @Tatu Ah, apologies. I keep forgetting what the exact low-rep limitations are at various rep levels. Judging by your profile, keep up the good work. :)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Not a problem :) Thanks for the insight, though!